# How to Store Image in App Specific Folder? IN Android 11. Help to Store Image

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is My Code the way I'm creating my folder in app Specific directory.

```
  private File createDirectory(String dirName) {
    File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(dirName) + "/" + dirName);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
    }
    return file;
}
```

Comment: And???? What is the question?

Comment: How to Store Image in App Specific Folder? IN Android 11. Help to Store Image 

This is the question. how to store image in the folder created with above code in app specific directory folder

Comment: Please put what you want in your post. Then put any question in your post. Write a decent post to begin with. Dont use comments for that. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

your method returns `File`, which is a directory. now you have to create new image file object

```
File dir = createDirectory("imagesDirectory");
File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), "imageName.jpg");
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

now you have to compress your `Bitmap` as JPG (as name set above) and feed this stream

```
Bitmap pictureBitmap = ...; // your image
pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outStream);
```

and don't foregt to close stream

```
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

if you want lossless format you can use PNG ([`Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat)), don't forget to name your file extension accordingly

Answer (score 0):

you can only write in your `app-specific` files

```
File dir_ = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "YOUR_DIR");
dir_.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function "getExternalFilesDir" and you change the value between in parenthesis. Here I put "Environment.DIRECTORY8DCIM" but there are others (you can check in the android developer web site).

I show you an exemple:

```
private fun getOutputMediaFile(): File? {


        val mediaStorageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).let {
                File(it, "[name_folder]").apply { mkdirs() } }

        Log.v(TAG, "storage: $mediaStorageDir") ///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[name_of_your_program]/files/DCIM/[name_folder]

        if (!mediaStorageDir?.exists()!!){
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Failed to create directory")
                return null
            }
        }
}
```

Hope that work for you :)

Comment: This if how you get an especific folder to storage your image. Now if you don't know how to save it, I leave you some usefull links :

https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/take-photo

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback